# Data-dismiss modal not working in angular on clicking submit

Tags: angular

Here is the code:

```
 <button [disabled]="submitEnable" 
             type="button" 
             class="btn btn-primary " 
             name = "button"   
             (click) ="onSubmit(addNewconnection.value);
             addNewconnection.reset()"
             data-dismiss="modal" 
             class="btn btn-success">
    Submit</button>
```

Please Full HTML code

Comment: Full code example please + Angular version

Answer (score 0):

***I dont know Full HTML Code but you can use Like this***

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">open</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <form [formGroup]="popupfrm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="  form-group form-group-margin  user-input-wrp ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control permit-input inputwidth inputText " max="16" name="name"
              formControlName="name" required />
            <span class="floating-label">Name</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group labelmargin user-input-wrp">
            <label class="label labelfont">Body:</label>
            <textarea [froalaEditor] formControlName="Message" rows="5" name="TranslationMailMessage" character="256"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="button-div">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-add btn-border">Add</button>
            <button type="submit" click='close()' class="btn btn-default btn-add btn-border">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button [disabled]="submitEnable" type="button" class="btn btn-primary " name="button" (click)="onSubmit(addNewconnection.value);
          addNewconnection.reset()"
            data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">
            Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```